# Openbox - How to automatically suspend on idle?

Tags: hibernate, openbox, pm-utils

Environment: Ubuntu 14.04 bare minimal + Openbox

I have installed `pm-utils`. Specfically, `pm-suspend` works great on my laptop. However, I have to run it manually.

I am wondering if there is a way to set Openbox to automatically suspend after, say, 15 minutes of idle time.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution I found:

```
sudo apt-get install xautolock
```

Add the following to your `~/.config/openbox/autostart` file:

```
xautolock -time 10 -locker "sudo pm-suspend" &
```

Now the computer will go in suspend mode after 10 minutes of inactivity.

Comment: I use this solution with `slock`